# Calculate diff in data.frame

Tags: r

I'm trying to calculate the returns from a data.frame of prices.

```
diff((na.locf(precos_mes))
```

Some of the columns have NAs as values, so to remove them I use locf function, but when I apply diff over it, it returns the following error:

```
(list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

And when I try to unlist it, I lose all the information from each stock vector.

```
diff(as.numeric(unlist(na.locf(prices))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
 lapply(precos_mes, function(x) diff(na.locf(x)))
```

Or if you don't need to remove the `NA` values at the beginning

```
 sapply(precos_mes, function(x) diff(na.locf(x, na.rm=FALSE)))
```

#### data

```
 set.seed(24)
 precos_mes <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(NA,0:4), 20*5,
              replace=TRUE), ncol=5))
```